# SSH - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, fedora, public-key

It's another SSH issue. It worked before updating to Fedora 33, but now it doesn't which makes me believe it's a client side issue. Anyone seeing something in the logs which could give a clue? Unfortunately 'm just a hobbyist, not an expert.

ssh -vvv logs:

```
ssh testuser@testserver -vvv
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host testserver originally testserver
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host testserver originally testserver
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512]
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "testserver" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to testserver [111.111.111.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to testserver:22 as 'testuser'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from testserver
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:IM4bKknzoKNTV6xGlCYGhs0e0VwhgOhDIdQO7AmJeQQ
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from testserver
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/test/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 111.111.111.111
debug1: Host 'testserver' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/test/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: testuser@testserver RSA SHA256:WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/test/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: testuser@testserver RSA SHA256:WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
testuser@testserver: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Pretty much the only server log entry hinting at something
server log:

```
testserver sshd[1111]: Connection closed by ip [preauth]
```

It is an old debian machine, if that gives any clues.

Comment: Do you have any other way to access the machine so you can see what's inside /etc/ssh/sshd_config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent releases from RedHat governed distributions disable some of the cryptographic  algorithms considered obsolete or insecure.

Judging from the line:

```
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

your server is probably using one of these disabled algorithms and doesn't allow something your client considers secure.

The systemwide crypto consiguration is setup by `update-crypto-policies` command and the default is `DEFAULT`.

You can enable most (if not all) of obsolete/insecure algorithms by downgrading to LEGACY crypto policy:

```
update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Saying the above, please consider upgrading your old server to something more modern.

Comment: This was pretty much it after all. Thanks!

Adding `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` does the trick for now and yes i'm trying to let it get upgraded already.